# Two proofs of the symmetry of second partial derivatives: only one is valid, right?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification, proof-explanation, partial-derivative

$\def\RR{\mathbb{R}}$
$\def\bv{\textbf{v}}$
$\def\bw{\textbf{w}}$
$\def\bu{\textbf{u}}$
$\def\bx{\textbf{x}}$
$\def\a{\alpha}$
$\def\D{\Delta}$

Below are two proofs of the symmetry of second partial derivatives. I merely wish verification that the first proof is valid, whilst the second is not.

---

**Theorem:** Let $f$ be a function $\RR^n\to \RR^m$. If $\partial_{\bv}\partial_{\bw} f$ and $\partial_\bw\partial_\bv f$ exist and are continuous on some open set $V'$ (for some $\bv, \bw\in \RR^n$), then
$$\partial_\bv\partial_\bw f = \partial_\bw\partial_\bv f \ \text{(on $V'$)}.$$

---

It is sufficient to prove the result for a function $\RR^n\to\RR$, so both arguments below restrict themselves to that case. For a function $g:\RR^n\to \RR$, a vector $\bu\in\RR^n$ and a nonzero scalar $h\in\RR$, we let
$$\D_{\bu,h}g(\bx) := \frac{g(\bx+h\bu)-g(\bx)}{h}.$$

**Proof #1:** The sketch of this proof is as follows:
$$\partial_\bv\partial_\bw f(\bx)
 = \lim_{t\to 0}\D_{\bw,t}\D_{\bv,t}f(\bx)
 = \lim_{t\to 0}\D_{\bv,t}\D_{\bw,t}f(\bx)
 = \partial_\bw\partial_\bv f(\bx).$$
The second equality is trivial. We prove the first equality (the third is shown similarly). We wish to move freely in the $\bv$ and $\bw$ directions, so choose $t$ such that $\bx + t_1\bv + t_2\bw \in V'$ for all $t_1,t_2\in[0,t]$. Now observe that
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\D_{\bv,t}\D_{\bw,t}f(\bx) 
 = \partial_\bv \D_{\bw,t}f(\bx+\a_\bv t\bv)
 = \D_{\bw,t}\partial_\bv f(\bx+\a_\bv t\bv)
 = \partial_\bw\partial_\bv f(\bx+\a_\bv t\bv + \a_\bw t\bw)
\end{split}
\end{equation}
for $\a_\bv,\a_\bw\in (0,1)$, where both equalities use the **Mean Value Theorem**. Taking the limit as $t\to 0$ gives the desired result.
$$\blacksquare$$

The switch from $\partial_\bv \D_{\bw,t}f$ to $\D_{\bw,t}\partial_\bv f$ may seem unnecessary, so I was tempted to simplify the proof as follows:

**Proof #2:** The sketch now is as follows:
$$\partial_\bv\partial_\bw f(\bx)
 = \lim_{t\to 0}\D_{\bv,t}\D_{\bw,t}f(\bx)
 = \lim_{t\to 0}\D_{\bw,t}\D_{\bv,t}f(\bx)
 = \partial_\bw\partial_\bv f(\bx).$$
As before, the second equality is trivial. We prove the first equality (the third is shown similarly). We wish to move freely in the $\bv$ and $\bw$ directions, so choose $t$ such that $\bx + t_1\bv + t_2\bw \in V'$ for all $t_1,t_2\in[0,t]$. Now observe that
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\D_{\bv,t}\D_{\bw,t}f(\bx) 
 = \D_{\bv,t} \partial_{\bw,t}f(\bx+\a_\bw t\bw)
 = \partial_\bv\partial_\bw f(\bx+\a_\bv t\bv+\a_\bw t\bw)
\end{split}
\end{equation}
for $\a_\bv,\a_\bw\in (0,1)$, where again both equalities use the **Mean Value Theorem**. Taking the limit as $t\to 0$ gives the desired result.
$$\blacksquare$$

---

**Question:** proof **#1** is valid, while proof **#2** is not, right?

The reason as to why I believe the second proof is not valid is that when writing
$$\D_{\bv,t}\D_{\bw,t}f(\bx) 
 = \D_{\bv,t} \partial_{\bw,t}f(\bx+\a_\bw t\bw)$$
the $\a_\bw$ cannot be taken to be a constant, but rather it must depend on $\bx$. In particular

$$\D_{\bv,t}\D_{\bw,t}f(\bx) = \frac{1}{t}\left[\frac{1}{t}\Big(f(\bx+t\bv+t\bw)-f(\bx+t\bv)\Big) - \frac{1}{t}\Big(f(\bx+t\bw)-f(\bx)\Big)\right]$$
$$ \ \ = \frac{1}{t}\Big[\partial_\bw f(\bx+\a_\bw(\bx+t\bv)t\bw) - \partial_\bw f(\bx+\a_\bw(\bx)t\bw)\Big]$$
where $\a_\bw(\bx+t\bv)$ need not equal $\a_\bw(\bx)$. From here on the proof falls apart.

The first proof does seem to avoid such mistake: letting $g:\bx\mapsto \D_{\bw,t}f(\bx)$ we get that $g$ is differentiable with respect to $\bv$, with
$$(\partial_\bv g)(\bx) = \frac{\partial_\bv f(\bx + t\bw) - \partial_\bv f(\bx)}{t} = (\D_{\bw,t}(\partial_\bv f))(\bx)$$
justifying the switch from $\partial_\bv \D_{\bw,t}f$ to $\D_{\bw,t}\partial_\bv f$. Furthermore, the $\a_\bv, \a_\bw$ are indeed constants since
$$(\D_{\bv,t}g)(\bx) = \frac{g(\bx+t\bv)-g(\bx)}{t} = (\partial_\bv g)(\bx+\a_\bv t\bv)$$
for some fixed $\a_\bv\in (0,1)$ and so on.